# Windows Form - Running python script, redirected output delayed

Tags: c#, output-redirect

I'm running a windows form with a background worker to update a textbox based on the output of a python script. Its all working pretty well, except the redirected output is not in real time; its delayed pretty significantly.

Any ideas how I can increase the redirected outputs response time?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace JiraHeartBeat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        delegate void AppendTextDelegate(string text);
        BackgroundWorker Worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
            Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        }

        void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartButton.PerformClick();
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Worker.IsBusy)
            {
                Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        public void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Process pro = new Process();
            pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pro.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            pro.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
            pro.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);

            pro.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
            pro.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\Python27\\myscript.py\"";

            try
            {
                pro.Start();
                pro.BeginOutputReadLine();
                pro.BeginErrorReadLine();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000 * 60);
        }


        public void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                string temp = (e.Data) + Environment.NewLine;
                appendText(temp);

            }
        }
        public void appendText(string text)
        {
            if (ResultTextBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                ResultTextBox.Invoke(new AppendTextDelegate(appendText), new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                ResultTextBox.AppendText(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the issue is that Python does not redirect output until the script is complete. I believe IronPython will redirect while the script is running (have not tested this though), but unfortunately, regular Python must wait for the script to end before redirecting output.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the below line from the `Worker_DoWork`, I suspect it is delaying the execution of the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

```
Thread.Sleep(5000 * 60);
```

**EDIT**

Since the above approach was attempted and did not solve the problem entirely I investigated a bit further and confirmed that when capturing the output from a python script the response is delayed. However, by adding a call to `sys.stdout.flush()` I was able to get the desired behavior. Here is the python script I used which worked successfully in my test.

```
import time
import sys

for x in xrange(0,11):
    print x
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Actually, the issue is that Python does not redirect output until the script is complete. I believe IronPython will redirect while the script is running, but unfortunately, regular Python does not :(

Comment: I ran your code to confirm my suspicion. When I run it, the first call to the process immediately outputs  to the `TextBox` but the second call is delayed until `Thread.Sleep(5000 * 60);` completes. I'm fairly confident this is at least a contributing factor to your problem. I didn't execute a python process, instead I executed a separate console app I whipped together. Maybe you could try commenting out the line just as a test and/or using a different process as a means of further narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Console apps will reply in real time, but python scripts will not. Create a simple python script that prints 1 through 10, with a 1 second break in between each print and you will see that even if I were to move the thread.sleep out (which I did. I created a separate background worker which was triggered to start the countdown upon completion of Worker), it still will not output in real time.